# Posting multi dimensional form via jquery to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, multidimensional-array

i have a form.
first 2 inputs are simply a customer ID and an address ID.
Then the rest is a multidimensional form as the usuer can dynamically add more items.

```
<div class='invoice_object'>
    <input      name='item[1][quantity]'    type='text'  value=''/>
    <textarea   name='item[1][description]'     ></textarea>
    <input      name='item[1][unit_price]'  type='text'  value=''/>
    <input      name='item[1][amount]'      type='text'  value=''/>
</div>
```

ANother invoice object can be added with jquery and it would be like so:

```
    <div class='invoice_object'>
    <input      name='item[2][quantity]'    type='text'  value=''/>
    <textarea   name='item[2][description]'     ></textarea>
    <input      name='item[2][unit_price]'  type='text'  value=''/>
    <input      name='item[2][amount]'      type='text'  value=''/>
</div>
```

If i post it normally with a submit button then the $_POST variable will contain:

```
$_POST['customer']
$_POST['address']
$_POST['item'] {
                ['1'] {
                       ['quantity']
                       ['description']
                       ['unit_price']
                       ['amount']
                       }
                ['2'] {
                       ['quantity']
                       ['description']
                       ['unit_price']
                       ['amount']
                       }
                }
```

I've searched for hours and tried all sorts of versions or serialize and serializeArray.JSON decode etc
It seems you can only send a string to php from jquery. Using JSON can get it to the php file but $_POST always ends up just having 1 value and its a string of all the data.

i figured there must be a way of doing it... without manually making a function that dissects the string acording to where the square brackets are.

i could do with some advice please.
Thanx.
But without panually dissecting

**jquery**

```
    var x = $('#new_invoice').serialize();

    $.post("script/new_invoice_script.php", {
                    x                       
                    }, function(data) {     
                    console.log (data);
                    });
```

Comment: `$(form).serialize();` and use ajax to send this serialized form

Comment: Show your code that uses `serialize()`. If you're using it correctly, it should do what you want. Since it's not doing what you expect, you must be using it wrong, but we can't tell what you're doing wrong if you don't post it.

Comment: What about your js ?

Comment: sorry uploaded now. i have tried different ways of writing and ive used serializeArray() @Anant

Comment: Sorry here its there now @barmar

Comment: @RiggsFolly Why did you use that dup? The problem is that he wrote `{ x }` instead of just `x` in the `$.post` argument.

Comment: `{ x }` is short for `{ x: x }`, which will put the serialized data in `$_POST['x']`. Just use `x` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't put `x` inside another object. It's already in the format necessary for the `data` argument to `$.post`.

```
var x = $('#new_invoice').serialize();
$.post("script/new_invoice_script.php", x, function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

When you write `{ x }` it's the ES6 shorthand for `{ x: x }`. That puts the serialized input string into `$_POST['x']`.

Answer (score 0):

The .serialize() method creates a text string in standard URL-encoded notation. It can act on a jQuery object that has selected individual form controls, such as , , and : $( "input, textarea, select" ).serialize();

You need use .serializeArray()

Comment: See the Dup for an answer